# How to add an AD user the right to administer groups in AD

Tags: active-directory, groups

I search google without luck.
Basically I need to enable to 4 users to our domain do add and remove members to some of the AD groups. But only that, they must not have any other right.
I know it sounds simple and silly, but I've never before had the need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pay now for possibility to make a comment but since I don't have enough points here goes nothing:

You just need to go a tab called "Managed By" and set it as you want.Additionally tick the check box for "Manager can update membership list". it will grant write permission for the Member attribute.

Comment: Thank you will check that and give you a feedback. I assume by doing this way there can be only one manager per group.

Comment: you almost followed my logic. Create group for those 4 people, and assign target group to be managed by that group of 4 and there you go. Noone said that group can't be manager ;).

Comment: This is working, however, how can I tell the user now administer the groups? I do not wish to grant him access to the DC to do that?

Comment: that's fairly easy just let one of ppl from which you assigned rights allow/change access rights and that's it.